# Display converter cable / display adapter prevents boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, hdmi, displayport, display-adapter

I have an odd problem, concerning my newly bought graphics card and my monitor setup (2x DELL monitors, 1x TV). The graphics card has three DisplayPort slots and one HDMI slot. My primary monitor has a VGA and an HDMI slot, and since my TV needs also audio, I bought a converter cable from HDMI to DisplayPort for my primary monitor. While hotplugging works fine, booting does not. The DRAM and CPU LEDs light up and the PC refuses to boot. The monitor must be either off or unplugged during boot, while it can be hotplugged after startup.

The wording on the website for the converter cable was unclear, it only said that the first plug is HDMI and second one is DisplayPort. Assuming that the converter cable is only unidirectional and the direction was wrong, I bought an adapter, which specifically said, that the output source is HDMI (monitor, TV etc.) and the input source is DisplayPort (PC, notebook). However the same problem persists. During boot, my monitor must be either off or unplugged otherwise the system won't boot up. Interestingly the boot button and the status LEDs will light up, whenever the monitor is connected via the converter cable, when the PC is shut down. Also my secondary monitor uses a converter cable from VGA to DisplayPort and it works just fine without any issues.

I tried every DP slot, each with the same issue. Connecting my primary directly via HDMI works fine.

Any ideas, how to fix it or where the issue might lie?

System specification:

- **OS**: Windows 10 (22H2 (Build 19045.3930))
- **Graphics Card**: MSI AMD 6750 XT (Adrenalin 23.12.1 (newest))
- **Primary Monitor**: DELL S2240LC
- **Mainboard**: ASRock B760 PRO RS (BIOS 7.04 (newest))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter adapter was indeed the cause of the issue. Third [converter adapter](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B081GMCNNF?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) I bought, work's like a charm.